# How do I set another explicit invocation for my action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I added an intent as an implicit invocation to my action so I could use it as a deep link.
It works just fine if I do this, talk to [display name] [implicit invocation phrase]. 
Then, I added another sample invocation, speak to [display name] and this works fine as well with my deep link.
Now, so far in my intent the user has to say, "talk to chef and list all chicken recipes" or "speak to chef and list all chicken recipes" but I what I want to add is "ask chef to list all chicken recipes."
In this case, "list all chicken recipes" is the invocation phrase of the intent added as an implicit invocation, chef is the display name of the action.

Unfortunately, the agent returns an empty TTS when I try to use ask chef to list all chicken recipes.

What should I put in the sample invocation section ? talk to chef and speak to chef work fine but ask chef or adding the whole thing : ask chef to list all chicken recipes does not work.

Comment: The sample invocation section doesn't have any backend impact. Can you try the simulator to see what data is being captured?

Comment: Quite honestly, I have no idea why talk to joy tester or speak to joy tester invokes my action. I just assumed that adding it to sample invocations is all you need to do. Clearly, my assumption is wrong. The simulator does not capture any data when I use ask [display name] to invoke my action.

Comment: Does `ask [display name] ...` invoke the action?

Comment: No, it does not.